# What's the best way to show loading in Flutter

Tags: flutter

In iOS native , I can use AOP to add loading methods in UIViewController like this

```
@interface UIViewController (Loading)
- (void)showFullScreenLoading;
- (void)showLoadingFloatViewWithTitle:(NSString*) title;
@end
```

And I can show a loading view to be seen in anyplace like this:

```
[self showLoadingFloatViewWithTitle:@"processing"]
```

But in flutter , the ui is all build in widget'sbuild method , It seems not so coveniently to do something like this , I have to make some logic for every request to show/hide the loading view.

Is there any best practice in flutter for this situation?

Answer (score -1):

Firstly, just as a comparison, albeit strange, you *could* do something similar with Flutter:

```dart
class LoadingScreen extends StatefulWidget{
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return new LoadingScreenState();
  }
}
class LoadingScreenState extends State<LoadingScreen>{
bool isLoading = true;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (isLoading)
      return Container();
    else
      return NotLoadingScreen();
  }

  void ShowLoading(){
    setState((){isLoading=true;});
  }

  Widget NotLoadingScreen(){
    //Should be implemented in each screen that inherits this class.
    return Container();
  }
}
```

And when you create your screen, you could extend from LoadingScreen:

```dart
Class MyScreen extends LoadingScreen{
  Widget NotLoadingScreen(){
    // Here would have your screen UI code.
}
}
```

And this would give you a similar result to what you described.

However, this does not follow any recommendations from Flutter. You can [see that widgets are usually composed](https://docs.flutter.dev/resources/architectural-overview#composition) instead of inherited.

Following this principle, you should declare a widget that serves as a wrapper loading screen, which receives a child widget as parameter. This child parameter will represent every screen that may have a loading indicator:

```dart
class LoadingScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget child;
  final bool isLoading;

  const LoadingScreen ({super.key, required this.child, required this.isLoading});

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (isLoading)
      return Container();
    else
      return child;
  }

}
```

And you could use it by passing your screen as parameter:

```dart
[...]
return LoadingScreen(
         isLoading:true,
         child:OtherScreen(),
);
```

This would be an example of how you would follow the above example by composing widgets.

One thing that is worth noting is that by doing this the control of showing or hiding the loading will be above in the widget tree. This may not suit your needs. In order to put it inside the child screen, you would need a better state management approach. A simple callback could work, or in more complex cases you could use other approach that exposes a method to a whole segment of the widget tree. Inherited widgets or packages like Provider can do this. You can read more about it [here](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple).

Comment: Thanks @Naslausky, Bu it still sems that the ' LoadingScreen(
         isLoading:true,
         child:OtherScreen(), ' is some kind of coupling and if you want to make some floating loading not fullscreen loading , this way seems hard to reuse

Comment: I see. It all depends on how do you organize your widget tree and how do manage your state. This answer was just a general guideline to point out the differences in which you can create your widgets.